# TClientSocket, TServerSocket и TEdit

Tags: delphi, сокет, клиент-сервер

Есть ли возможность передать через Socket три и более значений Edit'ов?
А на клиенте принять их в три Edit'a?
Или как такую вот задумку реализовать?
Может быть другим путём идти?

Comment: Если вы можете передать хотя бы 1 байт, то это значит, что вы можете передать любой(!) объем информации, повторив передачу 1 байта много(!) раз.

Answer (score 1):

Используя (например) нижеприведенные функции, записываете содержимое этих трех TEdit в поток, поток передаете корреспонденту, на котором так же последовательно вытаскиваете содержимое и отдаете в нужные TEdit`ы.

```pascal
procedure StringToStream(const s: string; Stream: TStream; Encoding: TEncoding = nil);
var
  b: TBytes;
  Len: integer;
begin
  if not Assigned(Encoding) then
    Encoding:=TEncoding.UTF8;
  b:=Encoding.GetBytes(s);
  Len:=Length(b);
  Stream.Write(Len, SizeOf(integer));
  if Len<>0 then
    Stream.Write(b[0], Len);
end;

function StreamToString(Stream: TStream; Encoding: TEncoding = nil): string;
var
  b: TBytes;
  Len: integer;
begin
  if not Assigned(Encoding) then
    Encoding := TEncoding.UTF8;
  Stream.Read(Len, SizeOf(integer));
  SetLength(b, Len);
  if Len<>0 then
    Stream.Read(b[0], Len);
  Result := Encoding.GetString(b);
end;
```

Главное - перед передачей и после приема потока не забыть сделать `Stream.Seek(0, soBeginning);`